# How to prevent Mobaxterm SSH browser from automatically disconnecting?

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

when using mobaxterm SSH browser, it will disconnect after a while and even if you selected send SSH keepalive in settings->SSH.  It still does so. Is there any way to persist SSH browser over a longer time?

Answer (score 6):

Did you try to select for the SSH browser SCP protocol instead of SFTP ?

I think it should be more stable as it is linked to the SSH session itself.

You can find this option in your session advanced settings under SSH browser type.

Comment: When I select SCP, I suddenly cannot open files anymore...

Answer (score 4):

Go to Settings, Configuration, SSH and activate **SSH keepalive** to send data every 60 seconds.

https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html#6_8_4

Comment: I have this checked but it my SSH-Browser still times out after some time

Comment: Then you have to reduce the number of `ServerAliveInterval` somehow https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config